# Android Accessibility - Switch Access - Custom Hyperlink Click Handle

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am working on an app and facing an issue with Accessibility with Switch Access. 
There is a TextView that shows HTML based text from the server. The text may contain multiple hyperlinks. These hyperlinks take the user to both internal Activities or external URLs. 
To support link clicks, there is a method which is called onClick of the link using CustomURLSpan class.
Everything works fine and the Talkback Accessibility also works perfectly. However, Using Switch Access shows a different Popup window compared to Talkback, and the onClick method is never called either crashing the Accessibility Engine or having no operation onClick of the Internal Reference Links. The external URLs work fine.
What is the issue here and how can I resolve it? 
The View Order link is an internal reference link which works fine using Talkback but have no response while using Switch Access.

**TalkBack Popup** (Local Context Menu)
[image]

**Switch Access** Popup
[image]